# How to get review count Google Place API?

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to find review count in Google Place API. I am looking at this link : https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details

So how to find the total review count?

Should I just count the response of review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot count response of reviews, because google returns max 5 reviews. So if the reviews are greater than 5 than then this method will fail.

To solve this problem, I am using `user_ratings_total` parameter.